# Passing an object that can be two different types, to a function in c#

Tags: c#

I want to have a function that receives either an sqlDataAdapter or a regular oleDataAdapter as on object parameter let's call it dbAdapter. I then want to use dbAdapter to access rows that are associated with whichever data adapter was passed to the function. Is this possible? I wanted to avoid passing a parameter to tell which one to use and then have an if statement with a set of almost identical code for each case. So, hypothetically, the function would be something like:

```
private void LoadRow(object dbAdapter, int theRow)
  {
     txtID.Text = dbAdapter.Rows[theRow]["ID"].ToString();

  }
```

and the call would look something like:

```
LoadRow(sqlDbAdapter, 1);
```

Or

```
LoadRow(oleDbAdapter, 1);
```

Where sqlDbAdapter is declared as an SqlDataAdapter and oleDbAdapter is declared as an OleDataAdapter.

I guess I could pass the function a value indicating which one to use and then an if statement to create which ever data adapter to use to the same variable name....like:

```
if (adapterType = "sql")
  {
     SqlDataAdapter dbAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter;
  }
else
  {
     OleDataAdapter dbAdapter = new OleDataAdapter;
  }
```

I think all the commands and other parameters of each adapter type are the same.... But I would like to pass the object by reference if that is possible...

Please give me your ideas and suggestions....

Thanks!

Valhalla

Comment: The both have a common type `DbDataAdapter`. Does this type contain everything you would want it to do?

Comment: The whole purpose of inheritance in OOP is so you won't have to switch on types. The function should take a DbDataAdapter, and you shouldn't care if it's a SqlDataAdapter or a OleDataapter or a FooBarDataAdapter.

Comment: Also, it sort of looks like you're confusing a DataAdapter and a DataTable. IDbDataAdapter doesn't have a Rows property, a DataTable does.

Comment: Thanks for the response....Yes I did not put that down right.... The only thing that really differs, for what I'm doing, between connecting to an SQL Server database and an Access database is the data adapter and connect string. Once I'm in LoadRow the data table would be the same for either adapter. Oh DbDataAdapter was just an arbitrary name not a class I made. I want to pass an SqlDataAdapter or an OleDataAdapter and I think overloading is what I had in the back of my mind. It was just so far back there  I couldn't remember it...:)

Answer (score 1):

If you *have* to do it this way, I'd use extension methods:

```
public static string LoadRow(this SqlDataAdapter adapter, int theRow)
{
    //return something you need
}

public static string LoadRow(this OleDataAdapter adapter, int theRow)
{
    //return something you need
}
```

Usage would be like:

```
myOleDataAdapter.LoadRow(9);
mySqlDataAdapter.LoadRow(5;
```

**Edit** - To answer the critics, if `IDbDataAdapter` has everything in it that you need, you can do this instead because both of the adapters you are trying to use implement it.

```
public static string LoadRow(this IDbDataAdapter adapter, int theRow)
{
    //return something you need
}
```

Comment: Or you could have ONE extension method:

public static string LoadRow(this IDbDataAdapter adapter, int theRow)...

Comment: Assuming that covers everything he needs which he hasn't stated whether it does or not.

Comment: Will the IDbDataAdapter connect to an SQL Server Database and an Access database? I assume it would fill a data table.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be:

```
private void LoadRow(DbDataAdapter dbAdapter, int theRow){
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dbAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
    txtID.Text = dataSet.Tables["myTable"].Rows[theRow]["ID"].ToString();
}
```

But **use it carefully** since the `.Fill()` method could result slow if used many times on a large data set.
My advice is to fill the data set just once and use it as much as possible and then release it, or if it isn't meant to become too large, keep it in memory and refresh it when you think it's apportune.

Answer (score -3):

An easy option is to over load the method, just create it twice one with the object being a SqlDataAdapter and the other time having it be an OleDataAdapter.

Comment: It's viable, but not *good*. What if he needs to support OracleDataAdapter and PgDataApapter, and dataadapters that haven't been invented yet?

Comment: @aquinas I answered the quested asked... you could also say too then what if he needed a property for a SqlDataAdapter which an OleDataAdapter doesn't have?  just passing dbDataAdapter wont handle that but he didn't say he would need to do that so is that why it doesn't matter?